# htaccess to skip a folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I see htaccess questions all over the place but I cant seem to get the thing to do what I want. Im not sure if a redirect or a rewrite is what I need.

Im looking for a way to use a sub folder but make it look there is not a subfolder.

I have a bunch of folders in the root of my domain:

```
www.mysite.com/folder1
www.mysite.com/folder2
www.mysite.com/folder3
www.mysite.com/folder4
```

Id like to be able to move folder1 and folder2 to a subfolder but not have that folder visible to the user. For example

```
www.mysite.com/x/folder1
www.mysite.com/x/folder2
www.mysite.com/folder3
www.mysite.com/folder4
```

But the user would still see it as it originally was.

It seems like I would have to use a redirect and a rewrite. If a user goes to `www.mysite.com/folder1` the will actually be in `www.mysite.com/x/folder1` without knowing that they are in that subfolder.

Of course I  need to do this without disrupting folder4 and folder5. Ideas? Tips? Tricks? Im not too familiar with htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me, maybe it will help someone else:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
```

This is telling the server to ignore the Public folder, so when my URL is actually mysite.com/public/file it shows and responds to mysite.com/file